# Need to implement a web-scraper to compile a database of images from https://diatoms.org/species

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For a research project, I am trying to implement a script that will go through this site and save the set of images from each species, with the file saved as "genus_species_index.jpeg". I have been looking at Beautiful soup tutorials as well. The main issue is that accessing each species page via script has proved to be quite difficult.

Comment: Difficult how? What specific problems are you having? Can you show us your code, and some sample input/output?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) to solve your problem. Beautiful soup is a parser (that does a great job of what you are looking for) but does not handle the crawling. Generally when doing tasks like this you will first scrape the site and then parse it to extract the data and spiders like scrapy were invented for the first purpose. (here is a link for some context: https://www.scrapehero.com/a-beginners-guide-to-web-scraping-part-1-the-basics/)